# Isn't projection transformation also not identity transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

since $P^2$ is $P$, can't we say $P$ is $I$ ?

like pre-multiply by $P^{-1}$

Comment: No, take diagonal matrix $P=diag(1,0)$. It is not invertible, but satisfies $P^2=P$.

Comment: What kind of projection are you talking about?

Comment: umm, it's just called projection transformation, P^2 = P

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. Yes it's basic, but it looks like a legitimate confusion for a first year student.

Comment: I agree @Yanko; it's short and basic, but nonetheless OP shares his own thought/idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> since $P^2$ is $P$, can't we say $P$ is $I$ ?
>
> like pre-multiply by $P^{-1}$

This requires $P$ to be invertible, which isn't necessarily so.

Take for example the projection in $\mathbb{R^2}$ onto the $x$-axis, given by the matrix:
$$P=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
Verify that $P^2=P$ but $P \ne I_2$; but also that $\det P = 0$ so $P$ is not invertible.

---

Note: your reasoning does show that the *only invertible projection* is in fact the identity (corresponding to the matrix $I$), but that's not a very interesting projection...

Answer (score 0):

**No, there are idempotent matrices other than the identity matrix:** In your reasoning, you are asserting that if $P=P^2$ (i.e., if $P$ is idempotent) then you must have:

$$I = P^{-1} P = P^{-1} P^2 = (P^{-1} P) P = I P = P.$$

This reasoning is valid only if $P$ is non-singular (i.e., invertible).  Thus, you can legitimately say that if $P$ is idempotent *and non-singular* then it must be the identity matrix.  However, there are many singular matrices that are idempotent, for which $P^{-1}$ does not exist, and so the above reasoning does not apply.  These matrices are [projection matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix), which are diagonalisable matrices where some of the eigenvalues are zero and the remaining eigenvalues are one.

Answer (score 0):

No. The inverse $P^{-1}$ is only defined if $P$ is, well, invertible, in which case the multiplying by $P^{-1}$ gives $P = I$, so $I$ is the only invertible projection matrix. But there are other projection matrices, for example, the zero matrix.

In fact, using the definition of projection to conclude that (1) any projection is diagonalizable, (2) any eigenvalue of a projection is $0$ or $1$, and (3) any transformation satisfying (1) and (2) is a projection. Thus (at least for finite-dimensional vector spaces) the projections $P$ are precisely the linear transformations for which there is a basis with respect to which the matrix representation of $P$ is $$\operatorname{diag}(1, \ldots, 1, 0, \ldots, 0) .$$